# Why does this command 'hiccup'?

Tags: vim

I have the following filter command:

```
vnoremap    <silent> <leader>C   :w! !pbcopy<CR><CR>
```

Yet, when I run it, there is a short 'hiccup', as shown in the video here: https://gyazo.com/ca78c5adfcf4b3b7a6a9f885acb5c8bc. Why does this occur? It seems to be inputing the command 'invisibly' or something (such as the extra command line that often occurs after an input command or echom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run the command "by hand" you'll see that after the first `<CR>` (when you press enter the first time, when the command gets executed) vim enlarges the status bar displaying the output of the command and a message that says:

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

then you press enter again (the second `<CR>` in the remap) and the status bar shrinks again. I think the "hiccup" is due to this status bar fast "enlarge and shrink" which causes a screen redraw and is also the reason why you need a double `<CR>` in the remap.

Comment: thanks, would doing `silent w! !pbcopy<cr>` fix that?

Comment: @David542 yes, `:silent` will probably fix that, but note the `<silent>` you already have in your remap is not the same as `:silent`, see `:help <silent>`. I think the correct syntax to fix the issue is `vnoremap <silent> <leader>C :exe ":<C-U>silent '<,'>w ! pbcopy"<CR>`